# Can we delay responding to a XMPP presence subscription?

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am using a PacketListener to receive XMPP packets.

If I receive the following:

```
<presence from="jeanne@belle.com" to="betty@belle.com" type="subscribe"/>
```

is the XMPP server expecting me to respond immediately ?

- **Motivation**: I want to cache all these subscription requests and allow the recipient to selectively ACCEPT/DENY (à la facebook invitations).
- Is there an API in which I can request for all subscription requests from openfire ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do NOT need to reply immediately or even in a given session; the server stores the fact that you have a pending inbound subscription, and will re-inform you of the pending subscription every time you log in.  Therefore, there should be no need to request the list either.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if you know of any forums that discusses XMPP.

Comment: The http://xmpp.org site is where you want to go.  Specifically, the mailing lists at http://xmpp.org/about/discuss.shtml.